# How to initialize a structure field std::map<std::string, std::string> called params

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct

I'm trying to initialize a structure using some data being held in a `std::vector<tokens>` - tokens are simply strings. My struct is:

```
struct parsedBlock{
std::string name;
std::map<std::string, std::string> params;
} 

parsedBlock block;
```

tokens[0] is block.name so it's simple to just write `block.name = tokens[0]`
But the question is how to intialize a params field supposing that key is `tokens[i]` and value is `tokens[i+1]`. Thanks in advance. Greetings!

Comment: It seems that what you're asking for is assignment, not initialisation.

Comment: I'd actually like to see more source code to better illustrate what you are asking about. This is a bit too terse and broad.

Comment: This does seem like a very specific use case - your title even references a specific variable name that's not likely to be useful in searches. John's showed the most obvious approach which is just a basic loop - is there something more you need here? I'm not entirely sure whether you've encountered a problem or summat.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your "tokens" vector contains the name at index 0 as a special value, and all successive values are the keys/values you want in the "params" map.

Worded differently, odd indexes (1, 3, 5, etc.) being keys of the "params" map, and even indexes (2, 4, 6, etc.) - except 0 - being values of the "params" map.

Assuming your "tokens" vector is correct, you can do something like this :

```
for (int i = 1; i < (tokens.size() - 1); i += 2) {
    std::string& key = block.params[i];
    std::string& value = block.params[i + 1];
    block.params.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(key, value));
}
```

Using (tokens.size() - 1), as the maximum "i" can go up to, ensures to not throw a std::out_of_range exception in case the "tokens" vector has a key (on a odd index) but no value (on an even index).

Using std::map::insert() method does insert the new key/value pair **only if the key does not already exist** in the map. Another way to insert a key/value pair in a map **and override the value if the key already exists** is to use the **[] operator** like so :

```
block.params[key] = value;
```

**Additional notes :**

1. compiler optimization should get rid of the references-creation step, and directly pass "tokens" vector values to the std::map::insert() method, avoiding a superfluous overhead by creating useless-but-increasing-readability references.

Comment: I'd go further and make those refs `const`. `const auto& key = block.params[i]; const auto& value = block.params[i+1]; block.params.emplace({key, value});`

Comment: Well the problem there is a little bit more nested as tokens[0] is name, indeed but the rest of tokens are filled in this way: token[1] is a key token[2] = " = " and token [3] is a value, tokens[4] is another key tokens[5] is " = " and tokens[6] is another value and so on and so forth. So would it be a proper solution to implement something like this:

`for (std::size_t i = 1; i < tokens.size(); i++){
 if(tokens[i] == " ="){
  std::string& key = block.params[i-1];
  std::string& value = block.params[i+1];
  block.params.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(key,value));
 }
}`